# Reading records with limits on lengths of fields

Tags: python, string, parsing

Suppose I have several records in a text file. 
 They are separated from each other by a blank line (i.e. `\n\n`).

All records follow the same format: in each record:

- there are a fixed number of fields,
- fields are separated by either a comma or a new line character `\n`. (so a field must be inside a single line).

In each field of a record:

- A new line character is never a part of any field, while a comma can be a part of a field.
- each field has a certain limit on its length (in terms of number of characters), which is provided from user inputs.
- if a field has characters fewer than its limit, it must ended with a newline character `\n`
- if a field has another field following it on the same line, it must reach its length limit, and is separated from the following field by a comma.
- a field can be empty, i.e. a blank line (which is also the record separator, but we know the number of fields in each record, so we can distinguish between the two cases)

E.g.

A user specify that each record has four fields named `A, B, C, D`, with limits 4, 3, 10, 5 on their lengths. There are two records in the text file:

```
aaaa, bb
ccc
ddddd

 ee ,fff
gggg,ggg
hhhh
```

How can we write a program to read the text file into a list of dictionaries, with each dictionary representing a record:

```
>>> records[0] 
{'A':'aaaa', 'B':' bb', 'C':'ccc', 'D':'ddddd'}
>>> records[1] 
{'A':' ee ', 'B':'fff', 'C':'gggg,ggg', 'D':'hhhh'}
```

Note: The leading or trailing whitespaces in a value of a field don't matter

Thanks.

---

**A more difficult problem** is:

- we allows  a single certain field to span one or more than one lines, and knows which field it is.
- we also know its following field always reach length limit
- No other fields can span more than one lines

For example, let's change the above example, by allowing the third field to span more than one lines. Change the second record to be

```
 ee ,ff
ggg
g,ggg
hhhhh
```

where the third field `C` is:

```
ggg
g,ggg
```

How can we implement that?

Comment: *"Can we implement that?"* - yes, probably.

Comment: Is this file specification something you can change? Because as it is, it's really odly designed and seems to do nothing but increase the possibility for errors. Why even allow multiple fields on the same line if a blank line is your "row" delimiter? And given the requirements to have field on the same line (they must be full-length), the comma is totally unnecessary, the delimitation is implied by the field-width. And do I count whitespace before/after the comma as part of the previous/next field, or does a field not start/end until the last/first non white-space character?

Comment: @aruisdante: Thanks. (1) I can't change it. Someone dumped some view from an Oracle DB into some csv file. I don't have access to the DB. I haven't used Oracle DB before, and don't know why the dump looks this way.  (2) we may think about the simpler case, if the difficult one is not easy. (3) A field starts immediately after a field separator, but the leading or trailing whitespaces don't matter (we can include them as part of the field)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at MULTILINE of the `re` module. 
What you describe is a rather well defined record, so a regex *like* the following will be able to parse it:

`re.compile(r"^.{1,4}[,]?.{1,3}[,]?.{1,10}[,]?.{1,5}[,]?$", re.MULTILINE)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_records(fname, field_lengths):
  """Return list of dict, where
  each list represents a record,
  as requested in the problem.
  fname : str
    the filename
  field_lengths : list of int
    the specified field lengths
  """
  fields = tuple("ABCD")  #the specified field names
  fin = open(fname,"r")
  result = list()
  #could use a regex, but let's brute force it:
  #extract records one at a time from the file
  #(record extraction is delegated to `get_record`)
  keepreading = True
  while keepreading:
    try:
      result.append( get_record(fin, field_lengths) )
      _ = next(fin) #discard record separator
    except StopIteration:
      keepreading = False
  return result

def get_record(fin, field_lengths): 
  """Return list of str, representing one record.
  fin : filehandle
    the file for record extraction
  field_lengths : list of int
    the specified field lengths
  """
  n = len(field_lengths)
  record_strings = []  #list to hold one record
  line = next(fin).rstrip("\n")
  for i, l in enumerate(field_lengths):
    if len(line) <= l: #only one record on this line
      record_strings.append(line)
      if (i < n-1):
        line = next(fin).rstrip("\n")
    else: #multiple records on this line
      record_strings.append(line[:l])
      line = line[l:].lstrip(",")
  #now we have a record as a list of strings,
  #but the problem asks for a dict, convert it.
  result = process_record_strings(record_strings)
  return result

def process_record_strings(ss):
  """Return dict, mapping field names to values.
  Input `ss` is a list of strings representing a record.
  White space is stripped from these strings, as in the
  problem example.
  """
  A, B, C, D = map(lambda x: x.strip(), ss)
  return dict(zip("ABCD",(A,B,C,D)))

#Example use:
field_lengths = 4,3,10,5
print get_records("temp.txt", field_lengths=field_lengths)
```

Comment: Why bother to leave a half-filled in answer that doesn't generally address the OP's question? It doesn't say the first two fields will always have a comma; the OP wants to know how to distinguish between the results because it's not specified *a priori*. Leaving half of the original question unanswered "as an exercise" defeats the purpose of StackOverflow as a Q&A site because you didn't provide any logic or basis for implementing it. Had you, say, implemented it for AB, and said "doing similar for CD is left as an exercise" it would be more understandable (if it was also correct).

Comment: A code dump without explanation is't terribly helpful (and this one doesn't follow the style guide).